# Accessing Share Resources in WIndows 2008 Sever

Tags: windows

I am facing some issues while accessing share resources with in the network. For Exapmle

I am having two windows 2008 R2 server's with IP 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2. If i share a folder then i am able to access, but when i am trying access \192.168.1.2\C$ in another server then it prompts for an Password, even after mentioning the password the server is not accepting the password therefore i am not able to access any Drive in this way and vice versa this is happening in both the server's.Both the server's are in work group and i disabled firewall but nothing worked for me. can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 0):

The 'admin' shares in 2008R2 don't work as they used to be. I think you can still use them with the 'administrator' account (not subject to UAC) but not with a user that is just part of the administrator group. You can get this to work by changing the registry:

```
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

but that disables parts of UAC which you may not want.

I would recommend no to use the admin shares or if you have to use the real administrator account.